# transferring joomla from subdomain to main domain

Tags: joomla

i have my my website like abc.com/dev now i want to transfer it to abc.com,

what minimal changes should i do to make it work .

My website is in joomla is there way that i just move folder to main folder and add db setting.

Please guide i am new to joomla

Answer (score 0):

Just **Drag and drop** your folders from your subdomain folder to root folder **through FTP**.

Then only changes you need to do is in your '***configuration.php'*** file located at the root folder. If your DB is not changed then do not change any of its setting. Just change the path of ***'LOGS and TMP'*** folders in config file to the root path that are :

**$log_path, $tmp_path**

And I hope your site will work perfectly as it was working before.